# jQuery Zoom works sometimes and sometimes not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have now successfully installed jQuery zoom. But for no reason sometimes it works and sometimes not...

Take a look here

1. [Working](https://radlvoo.de/produkt/centurion-crossfire-2000-2017-rh-groesse-47/)
2. [Not Working](https://radlvoo.de/produkt/bergamont-trailster-8-0-plus-gent-2017-rh-groesse-xl/)

I also don't get a error in the console... What can be the reason for it and how can I fix that?

Kind regards

Comment: We can not debug your website ([ask]). You need to figure out a way to reproduce the bug and post the code here as a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really works. The one that doesn't work is because you have a transparent background on the image while the one what works have a white background.

Comment: Sorry... I missed that... But thank you!

Comment: no worries, glad to help.